# A question about normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

**Edited** : )

> Let $H$ and $K$ be two subgroups of $G$ such that $|H|=|K|$. Suppose that $(|H|,|G:H|)=1$, then $N_H(K)=N_K(H)=H\cap K$.

**Hint given:**

> Let $\pi$ denote the set of the prime divisors of $|H|~(\text{or } |K|)$. For convenience, we may call a natural number "$\pi$***-number***", if all of its prime divisors of are contained in $\pi$. Try to prove if $H\cap K$ is a proper subgroup of $N_H(K)~(\text{or } N_K(H))$, then $|N_H(K)|$ is also a $\pi$-number dividing $|G|$, which contradicts $(|H|, |G:H|)=1.$

I tried to develop the hint, but found something confusing to me. I think that just without $H\cap K$ being proper, $N_H(K)\leq H$ implies that $N_H(K) $ is certainly a $\pi$-number. But the given hint assumed $H\cap K$ to be proper, how does that help? And moreover, how can I develop the hint? I’m rather confused now... : (

**PS:** I must have missed certain things, but what are they? And how to solve this problem? More detail is in need, please. I'll be grateful if you could provide me a possible answer! Thanks!

Comment: Of course $\;H\cap K\le H,\,K\;$, but the hint talks about *assuming* that $\;H\cap K\lneq N_H(K)\;$ ...

Comment: The point is that you should find it clear that $H \cap K \le N_H(K)$ and $H \cap K \le N_K(H)$, so the problem is to prove the opposite inclusions. Then you assume for a contradiction that $H \cap K$ is a proper subgroup of $N_H(K)$. It seems clear that $|N_H(K)|$ is a$\pi$-number dividing $|G|$, so the problem really is to show that this contradicts $(|H|,|G:H|)=1$, which you should try and do.

Comment: Edited $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks.But how... I’ve tried many many times...

Comment: $N_H(K)K$ is a $\pi$-group, so we must have $N_H(K)K=K$, hence $N_H(K) \le H \cap K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subgroup $H$ with the set of prime divisors $\pi$ is called a Hall $\pi$-subgroup if $(|H|,[G:H])=1$. In particular Sylow $p$-subgroups are Hall subgroups. Recall the Sylow theorem stating that if a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ is normal in $G$, then any $p$-subgroup of $P$ is contained in $G$. Same statement applies to normal Hall subgroups. Since $H$ is normal in $N_G(H)$, any $\pi$ subgroup of $N_G(H)$ is contained in $H$. Consider the subgroup $N_K(H)$ of $N_G(H)$. If $N_K(H)$ properly contains $H\cap K$ then there is a prime dividing $[N_K(H):H\cap K]$ which is not in $\pi$. However this prime also divides $|K|$ and hence must be in $\pi$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! But why “If $N_K(H)$ properly contains $H\cap K$ then there is a prime dividing $[N_K(H):H\cap K]$ which is not in $\pi$”?

Comment: So, if $N_K(H)$ properly contains $H\cap K$, that means $N_K(H)$ cannot be a $\pi$ group. Otherwise, $N_K(H)$ would be subgroup of $H$ (since $H$ is a normal Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $N_G(H)$) and hence of $H\cap K$. Since this is not the case, $N_K(H)$ is not a $\pi$ group, which contradicts the fact that $N_K(H)\leq K$ which is a $\pi$-group.